# htaccess file in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I put this htaccess file in my base folder but still index.php is not removed. I am using xamp server.

can you help me please!

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /MMS/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your **application/config/config.php**? There should be:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

default value is:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I check your htaccess file and i removed

```
RewriteBase /MMS/
```

This line from your htaccess then its working.

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess file is looking fine. You need to change the base url in the config.php file like below:-

1)First step

```
 $base_url  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
 $config['base_url']    = $base_url;
```

This will work. Let me know if more help needed.

2) Second step:-

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

First solution is working fine for  me.